# Flutter display a notification for a long time like whatsapp call

Tags: flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

When i receive a call notification on whatsapp it stays on a screen for a long time.
I am trying to create same behaviour using flutter and FCM notification. I am  using below code
I am using same collapseKey but after showing notification two times the  notification appear in  background and not as heads-up notification.

```
callNotificationTimer = Timer(Duration(seconds: 8), () {
      
      sendPayLoad(
        fcmToken,
        collapseKey: collapseKey,
        callData: request,
        userData: userData,
      );
    });
    sendPayLoad(
      fcmToken,
      collapseKey: collapseKey,
      callData: request,
      userData: userData,
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend you to use this package: **flutter_incoming_call** to display a notification for a long time like whatsapp call

Comment: i am using webrtc for calls this plugin will not work and it is in development not ready for production